# Access HTML DOM lastModified Property from Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Is it possible to access the HTML DOM lastModified Property from Blazor without using Javascript?

The HTML DOM lastModified Property is descibed at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_lastmodified.asp

This example encloses demonstration code within HTML `<script>` tags.

I would like to display the value of the lastModified property on a Blazor Server side app's page footer using Blazor's razor page @Code {some C# code} feature, something like:

```
@code 
{
    public var DateDocumentLastModified = document.lastModified;
}
```

I have spent a couple of hours looking around for a method but have not been able to find any guidance.
Unraveling and following the MSDN [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1) procedure to find such a basic data element seems like a massive overhead to me.

Can anyone tell me if there is a method that uses only C# and avoids me having to enter the JavaScript world in this instance?

Comment: your question is vague, can you give us more info about your goal, maybe a small example

Comment: Hi Lucian.  Thanks for your interest.  I have added more detail.  Please tell me it it is adequate.

Comment: why don't you use HTML5 local storage inside Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage ?

Comment: Thanks Ali.  I hadn't heard of Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage
I've found a NuGet reference. Can you point me to any more "How-to"  doco and/or reference material please?

Comment: lastModified is a curious example in a SPA, it will change when you update the DOM to display it.

Comment: Thanks Henk. Can you point me to any examples/doco?